# Setting the default value for a text field as a variable in Form API

Tags: forms

I thought this would be straight forward but my lack of drupal knowledge is holing me back. I want to grab the email from the logged in user, and set it as the default value of the form. I can grab the email from the global user logged in, but cannot pass this to the form?

The email field is blank, but I have the email stored in `$email1` I want to place this value in the text box, as the default field.

```
global $user;
    $user_full = user_load($user->uid); 
    $email1= $user_full ->mail;
    echo $email1;

 $form['admin_email'] = array (
 '#type' => 'textfield',
 '#title' => t('Admin Email need email validation!!!'),
 '#description' => t('Please enter an Email'),
 '#default_value' => $user_full->mail,
 );
```

Comment: And? What's are the effects? PHP error? Form field empty by default? Something within Watchdog?..

Comment: Sorry i just get a blank field @Mołot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `user_load($user->uid);`. You already have a complete object inside `global $user;` variable. And don't forget PHP is *not* a natural languages. You can't just put whitespaces where you want them. In method call or property access, there should be no spaces around `->`, it should be right next to object, and property should be right after arrow.

This line is sufficient for me:

```
'#default_value' => $user->mail,
```

Comment: @Tom please edit your question and address concerns from my comment, OK? Now it's a bit unclear what's your problem, exactly.

Comment: The reason I was using the uid was because, i have custom profile fields that i want to add to the form fields. I read that to pull these I had to have the code as above rather than just global $user?

Comment: @tom if you want to use custom fields, ask about custom fields in your question. `mail` is a built in field. We cannot help you if you don't want to tell us what exactly are you doing.